# Discord.js: bot is unable to handle multiple commands with buttons correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, discord.js, interaction

I was creating a new help command for my discord bot when I encountered this problem:
**When two or more Help Commands are called, only the last one would handle the button interactions correctly, and all the others would mess up.**

My help command is divided in sub-menus that users can select with a StringSelectMenu.
Each sub-menu contains page(s) of commands of a same category.

## Example

When I call the `/help` command twice and go back interacting with the buttons of the first command, if I reach the last page of the sub-menu, the "Next" and "Last" buttons should be disabled, but they are not in this case. However, the last command still works as it should.

This issue also happens when I navigate back to the first page in the previous commands.

## Video demo of my problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWtvcNmrX80

## **What I think is causing this issue:**

I think the variable `currentPage` is static and shared between the commands.

However, when a second command is called, only this second command could update the value of `currentPage`, and since there is only a single `currentPage` shared between all the commands, the previous commands would be forced to use the value of `currentPage` of the last command, which modifies the page index of the previous commands to unwanted ones.

## **What I expect to happen:**

- When a user selects a new sub-menu, the "First" and "Previous" buttons are automatically disabled. If the sub-menu has more than one page, the "Next" and "Last" button are automatically enabled. Else, Disable all the buttons.
- When a user reaches the last page of the sub-menu, the "Next" and "Last" buttons are automatically disabled.
- When a user reaches the first page of the sub-menu, the "Previous" and "First" buttons are automatically disabled.
- When a user is in a page that is nor the first page nor the last page, all the buttons are enabled.

## **What I have tried:**

- Creating unique IDs for each button based on `interaction.id`.
- Logging the page index `currentPage` to track its changes.
- Reviewing the buttons' update conditions.
- Searching for other people's solutions, but none of them worked.
- Create sessions that give the users unique instances of `currentPage`.
- Use the Immediately Invoked Function Expression in order to limit the scopes.

## **My current code:**

- Full code of the command: https://pastebin.com/Ttv6YaY0
- Part of the code used to handle button interactions and to update page indexes:

```
// Handling received interactions from the collector
            collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
                if (i.user.id == interaction.user.id) {
                    // If the interaction received is not from the buttons nor from the select menu, do nothing.
                    if (!i.isButton() && !i.isStringSelectMenu()) return;
                    // Defer the reply since the command takes longer time than usual to complete
                    await i.deferUpdate();
                    // Button handling starts here
                    if (i.isButton()) {
                        // If the user is still on the starting menu, disable all the buttons
                        if (currentCategory == menu.init) {
                            for (const i of buttons) {
                                await i.setDisabled(true);
                            }
                            // User is not on the starting menu
                        } else {
                            // Update the page according to the interaction of the user
                            switch (i.customId) {
                                case "previous":
                                    currentPage -= 1;
                                    break;
                                case "next":
                                    currentPage += 1;
                                    break;
                                case "first":
                                    currentPage = 0;
                                    break;
                                case "last":
                                    currentPage = currentCategory.length - 1;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    handleError(
                                        i,
                                        "Unknown button interaction."
                                    );
                            }

                            // Disabled and enable certain buttons to avoid errors
                            // First page
                            if (currentPage == 0) {
                                await previousBtn.setDisabled(true);
                                await firstBtn.setDisabled(true);
                                // Re-enable in case disabled
                                await nextBtn.setDisabled(false);
                                await lastBtn.setDisabled(false);
                                // Last page
                            } else if (
                                currentPage ==
                                currentCategory.length - 1
                            ) {
                                await nextBtn.setDisabled(true);
                                await lastBtn.setDisabled(true);
                                // Re-enable in case disabled
                                await previousBtn.setDisabled(false);
                                await firstBtn.setDisabled(false);
                                // Middle pages
                            } else {
                                // Reenable all buttons in case disabled
                                for (const button of buttons) {
                                    await button.setDisabled(false);
                                }
                            }

                            console.log("BTN:", currentPage);

                            // Update the embed message;
                            await i.editReply({
                                embeds: [currentCategory[currentPage]],
                                components: [selectMenuRow, buttonsRow],
                            });
                        }
                        // Select Menu Handling
                    } else if (i.isStringSelectMenu()) {
                        // i.values[0] is the command category that the user had chosen
                        switch (i.values[0]) {
                            case "fun":
                                currentCategory = menu.fun;
                                break;
                            case "utils":
                                currentCategory = menu.utilities;
                                break;
                            case "welcomebye":
                                currentCategory = menu.welcome_goodbye;
                                break;
                            default:
                                currentCategory = menu.init;
                                break;
                        }
                        currentPage = 0; // Reset the page number
                        // Disable the previous and next buttons to avoid unexpected interactions
                        await firstBtn.setDisabled(true);
                        await previousBtn.setDisabled(true);
                        // If there are more than one page of help in that category, allow the user to move on the next pages
                        if (currentCategory.length > 1) {
                            await nextBtn.setDisabled(false);
                            await lastBtn.setDisabled(false);
                            // If there is only one page of help, disable all the buttons to prevent causing errors
                        } else {
                            await nextBtn.setDisabled(true);
                            await lastBtn.setDisabled(true);
                        }
                        await interaction.editReply({
                            embeds: [currentCategory[currentPage]],
                            components: [selectMenuRow, buttonsRow],
                        });
                    }
                    // A non-command-caller user tries to interact with the command
                } else {
                    await i.deferUpdate();
                    await i.followUp({
                        content: `This is not for you.`,
                        ephemeral: true,
                    });
                }
            });
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative method to handle my button interactions thanks to the help of fellow programmer. Here's the solution:

**I created a function that will use the two arguments `currentPage` and `maxPage` to update and return new button components. Every time I need to edit the button components, I could just pass this function in the `components` argument in `interaction.editReply()`.**

Conditions that will return boolean values are passed in the `setDisabled` function of each `ButtonBuilder()` so the buttons could disable themselves when condition is met.

Here's the function:

```
// A function used to update the buttons function
getButtons(currentPage, maxPage) {
    const components = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId("first")
            .setLabel("First Page")
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
            .setDisabled(!(currentPage > 0)), // Disable if user on first page
        new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId("previous")
            .setLabel("⬅️")
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
            .setDisabled(!(currentPage > 0)), // Disable if user on first page
        new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId("next")
            .setLabel("➡️")
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
            .setDisabled(currentPage == maxPage), // Disable if user on last page
        new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId("last")
            .setLabel("Last Page")
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
            .setDisabled(currentPage == maxPage) // Disable if user on last page
    );

    return components;

}
```